# Shorter version of Hibernate query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have hibernate query, for example get user by id:

```
public User findById(int id){
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;

    User user = null;

    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);


        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch(HibernateException e){
        if(null != tx) tx.rollback();
        System.out.println("HibernateException, transaction will be rollbacked");
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return user;
}
```

It's ok for one query, but i need dublicate all of this code to every query.
I need just on single code:

```
user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
```

Is it possible to put other code to another class, method or something else?

**Updated**
HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question ? `but i need duplicate all of this code to every query.` Do you need `User` object?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Means, for User class, For Role class, For Subject class, this code gets duplicated with one line change

Comment: yes, findUserByUsername, deleteUser, updateUser..... everything same, except one line of code

Comment: You can write SessionFactory utility class that will return you session object, you can use this utility in every class. And once you get the session object you can begin the transaction and execute the query.

Comment: Better write Utility class or HibernateTemplate for session management

Comment: There are thousands of examples Hibernate and Spring ... Read the manual. (And dont write your own utility class!)

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to keep one Hibernate utility class which will have a static method to provide us the hibernate session. Moreover you can reuse the hibernate session by preventing making a new session on each query by using some simple logic.